# Calculate the hue difference between two colors

Tags: colors, gimp

I'm using gimp 2.8.10 to try to change a color to another, or to be more specific **R: 187 G: 139 B: 91** to **R: 254  G: 225 B: 125**.

I have tried to do it on my own but haven't managed, so I wonder if it a tool out there where I can calculate what I need to set the Hue, Lightness, and Saturation to?

What I'm trying to do is change the skin color of a character into what it's suppose to be.

Comment: Its not clear what your question is exactly

Comment: Is there a tool I can use to calculate what I need to set the Hue, Lightness, and Saturation to get from one color, to another?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by tool? a piece of software? you're trying to change a color into what its supposed to be...WHAT? how do we know what it's supposed to be? everything about this screams vague. Software rec are considered off topic

Comment: @Sickest the question is tagged "gimp". Yemto is asking about tools within the GNU Image Manipulation Program.

Comment: @Yemto - Why do you need a tool?  You can just use pen and paper to do the simply subtraction calculations required to do this.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsl.htm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to know the **hue** difference between these two colours so you can aply a hue shift from one to another (maybe because there's many similar colored areas in the character's skin?).

If that's the case, you just need to look up the hue of your original colour (**30** for RGB(187,139,91)) and the one for your new color (**47** for RGB(254,225,125)). (Gimp provides these values.)

Since the difference is 47-30=17, if you add 17 to the original hue, you'll obtain the hue from the second color.

Beware that this shift **will not make** the first color into the second since they also have different **values** (73 and 100 respectively).

EDIT: Hue is easily shifted in GIMP by means of *Colors / Hue & saturation...* but I don't know how to play around with the value, since that menu offers Hue-Saturation-Lightness transformations instead of Hue-Saturation-Value.